# Efficient Algorithm to find combination of numbers for an answer

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, depth-first-search

I've been thinking of how to find an efficient algorithm to find any combination of numbers which sum/subtract/divide/multiply to a certain answer.

Eg.

```
Input:
Number set = {4,3,7,8}
Operator set = {+.-.*,/}
Answer = 68

Output:

    Equations = {((4*3)+(7*8)),((4+4)*7)+(4*3), etc}
```

- No repeated ( 3 * 7 / 7 = 3), or else infinite loop
- All numbers in the number set have to be used at least once
- Not all operators has to be used

I understand that probably there are potentially infinite solutions to this. What would be a good way to get the first 10 outputs?

My Attempt (Brute force):

Arrange the numbers in order (eg. 4 numbers, 4 operators)

```
n1 o1 n2 o2 n3 o3 n4 (eg. 4 + 3 * 7 + 8) (4^4 * 4^3 combinations)
```

Then, find the order of operations. `(eg. (n1 o1 n2) o2 (n3 o3 n4) )` (3! combinations)

Then, compare the answer with the provided answer and check for match.

The number of combinations increase exponentially. `(k^k * 4*(k-1) * (k-1)!)` combinations, if I'm not wrong.

How can I go about doing this efficiently?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ((4+4)*7)+(4*3)=> is it valid? there are three '4'. But in your set there is only one '4'.

Comment: A solution that will always work is to find *any* way to create a single `1`, and then just keep adding them up :) What is the criterium for "first 10"? Using any algorithm? No duplicates/invertations? I.e., is `4+3` different from `3+4`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the replies. I think the difficulty here is that numbers can be repeated, all numbers can be used more than once, and must be used at least once. I agree with (4+3) v (3+4). Probably have to find a way to limit that so that the algorithm can be more efficient.

Comment: "Allowing duplicates" is indeed different from the suggested duplicate. Your method would be able to find a solution where the dup may say there is none.